# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects with randint

Tags: python

Doing the following code

```
import easygui
from random import randint

Minimum = easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your minimum number")
Maximum = easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your maximum number")
operator = easygui.enterbox(  msg="which operator would you like to use? X,/,+ or - ?",title="operator")

rn1 = randint(Minimum,Maximum)
rn2 = randint(Minimum, Maximum)  

print "%s %s %s =?" %(rn1, operator, rn2)
```

Gives me this error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I know it is a confliction between the string and interger, but how do i fix it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: What line is your error occurring on? Let's see the whole stack trace.

Comment: the errors occur on 8 and 9

Comment: @JamesFletcher **edit the question** to provide the full traceback. Have you considered explicitly converting to `int`?

Answer (score 2):

`enterbox` returns a string. Convert the values to integers before storing them.

```
import easygui
from random import randint

Minimum = int(easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your minimum number"))
Maximum = int(easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your maximum number"))
operator = easygui.enterbox(  msg="which operator would you like to use? X,/,+ or - ?",title="operator")

rn1 = randint(Minimum,Maximum)
rn2 = randint(Minimum, Maximum)  

print "%s %s %s =?" %(rn1, operator, rn2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Minimum and Maximum are strings, not ints, so you can't pass them to randint as such.

Though you should probably watch out for exceptions if they enter something that's not an int you can do `randint(int(Minimum), int(Maximum))` and as long as they entered good numbers you'll be all set.